# Line not drawn in combo chart of visualization

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have data that contains Columns called `TestName` and `TestValue`.

With this, I want to draw a `Combo-chart` such that bars as well as Line  is rendered.

[Link to Combo Charts of Google](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart)

However, In my case, it either represents bars or line.

```
var options = {
                   title: 'TestType v/s TestValue on ComboChart',
                    vAxis: {title: 'TestValue',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
                     hAxis: {title: 'TestType', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}},
                     seriesType: "bars",
                     series: {0: {type: "line"}},
                    width:600,
                    height:400
                };
```

When I have `0` value against series, it renders only bars:

It is as follows:

[image]

I do not know the significance of this number against series. All that I really want is have bars and corresponding line on same chart.

**Edit:** I realize that combo charts work that way only when there are minimum of 2 series. Is there an alternative to combine graphs without compulsively having multiple series?

Comment: Given that you only have one series the only valid index is `0`.  
If you're asking to have a single series that is rendered as both a line and as a bar I don't think that can be done.  You'd have to create a second series with the same data and set one to `bars` and one to `line`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a view you can reuse the same column.

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["TestType", "TestValue"],
        ["BP", 120],
        ["Temperature", 100],
        ["Cholestrol", 80],
        ["Cavity", 1]
    ]);
    
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data); 
    view.setColumns([0,1,1]);

    var options = {

        title: 'TestType v/s TestValue on ComboChart',
        vAxis: {
            title: 'TestValue',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: 'red'
            }
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'TestType',
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: 'blue'
            }
        },
        seriesType: "bars",
        series: {
            0: {
                type: "line",
                color: "blue"
            },            
            1: {
                color: "blue",
                visibleInLegend: false
            }
        },
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    }


    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("chart"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```